# Why is impossible to mark desired kernel module for compiling, hidden dependences?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to recompile linux kernel in order to add some new modules into it.

But:
There is unable to check them in the xconfig to mark it as module or built in.

My approach:

1/ "Edit -> Find" type CX231XX into search box -> module options are found. All four modules are listed in the search window:

- Conexant cx231xx USB video capture support (VIDEO_CX231XX)
- Conexant Cx231xx ALSA audio module (VIDEO_CX231XX_ALSA)
- DVB/ATSC Support for Cx231xx based TV cards (VIDEO_CX231XX_DVB)
- Conexant cx231xx Remote Controller additional support (VIDEO_CX231XX_RC)

2/ But. They does not appear in the configuration window.

3/ When i switch "Option -> Show All Options", they appears in the module list, I can see them there, but they are unable to change status to M, or Y. They still stays unchecked.

There is probably some dependency issues, but im wrong if suppose that kind of things are solved automatically?

How do i compile cx231xx support into my kernel, plz ??

(4.4.26-gentoo x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4600 @ 2.40GHz GNU/Linux)

Comment: Dependencies are automatically enabled (as specified by the `select` keyword in the Kconfig entry).  But ***prerequisites*** have to be satisfied (i.e. already enabled) *before* an option is configuratble.  That is, all of the `depends on` options must be enabled.  Read the `help` text for the option(s) you're trying to enable.

Comment: @sawdust, one may use `make nconfig` and search there, It will show what exactly prevents module to be enabled.

Comment: Probably you need video4linux, do you enabled it on kernel (v4l2) ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that all dependences mentioned in the **help text for CONFIG_VIDEO_CX231XX**  I have already solved:

```
Symbol: VIDEO_CX231XX [=n]
Type : tristate
Prompt: Conexant cx231xx USB video capture support
Location:
-> Device Drivers
-> Multimedia support (MEDIA_SUPPORT [=m])
-> Media USB Adapters (MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT [=y])
Defined at drivers/media/usb/cx231xx/Kconfig:1
Depends on: USB [=y] && MEDIA_SUPPORT [=m] && MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT [=y] && (MEDIA_ANALOG_TV_SUPPORT [=y] || MEDIA_DIGITAL_TV_SUPPORT [=y]) && VIDEO_DEV [=m] && I2C [=m] && RC_CORE [=n]
Selects: VIDEO_TUNER [=m] && VIDEO_TVEEPROM [=m] && VIDEOBUF_VMALLOC [=m] && VIDEO_CX25840 [=m] && VIDEO_CX2341X [=m] && I2C_MUX [=m]
```

and my kernel:

```
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep MEDIA_SUPPORT
CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_USB=
CONFIG_USB=y
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT            
CONFIG_MEDIA_SUPPORT=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT
CONFIG_MEDIA_USB_SUPPORT=y
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_MEDIA_ANALOG_TV_SUPPORT
CONFIG_MEDIA_ANALOG_TV_SUPPORT=y
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_MEDIA_DIGITAL_TV_SUPPORT
CONFIG_MEDIA_DIGITAL_TV_SUPPORT=y
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV               
CONFIG_VIDEO_DEV=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_I2C=     
CONFIG_I2C=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEO_TUNER
CONFIG_VIDEO_TUNER=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEO_TVEEPROM
CONFIG_VIDEO_TVEEPROM=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEOBUF_VMALLOC
CONFIG_VIDEOBUF_VMALLOC=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEO_CX25840   
CONFIG_VIDEO_CX25840=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_VIDEO_CX2341X
CONFIG_VIDEO_CX2341X=m
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_I2C_MUX=
CONFIG_I2C_MUX=m
```

There is only **RC_CORE option which have some troubles**, because is missing:

```
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_RC_CORE
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep RC_CORE
alnagon ~ % zcat /proc/config.gz |grep CONFIG_RC     
# CONFIG_RCU_EXPERT is not set
CONFIG_RCU_STALL_COMMON=y
# CONFIG_RCU_EXPEDITE_BOOT is not set
# CONFIG_RCU_TORTURE_TEST is not set
CONFIG_RCU_CPU_STALL_TIMEOUT=21
# CONFIG_RCU_TRACE is not set
# CONFIG_RCU_EQS_DEBUG is not set
alnagon ~ %
```

**CONFIG_RC_CORE is not in kernel, but have to be solved**, so what..?

Background:
RC_CORE is option of specific, strange kind in kernel. **RC_CORE is auxiliary option**, which cannot be switched manually. It cannot be sloved in xconfig or menuconfig, but there is tool, which know about it. As mentioned 0andriy - thanks a lot - it is make nconfig. **F8 (SymSearch) in nconfig find RC_CORE and its dependences**.

```
Symbol: RC_CORE [=m]
Type  : tristate
  Defined at drivers/media/rc/Kconfig:1
  Depends on: MEDIA_SUPPORT [=m] && MEDIA_RC_SUPPORT [=y] && INPUT [=y]
```

And here it is. Hidden dependence is: **MEDIA_RC_SUPPORT** !!!

**So Answer is:**
If you want to compile VIDEO_CX231XX, you have to turn on also MEDIA_RC_SUPPORT.

Answer (score -2):

Also "make menuconfig" and search there shows what prevents the module to be built.

Rami Rosen

Comment: Why you are answering with comment-like posts?